# ssis vsta script component slow to open on edit VS2015

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Since upgrading visual studio 2015 and using ssis, we have experienced that the editor for Script Task/Component takes around 30 seconds to open.

i have seen some older posts suggesting to add "127.0.0.1 crl.microsoft.com" to the local hosts file. But has not impact on the issue i'm experiencing.

Really hope someone out there has had the same issue and maybe found a solution?

Comment: is the script editor calling a VS Shell or is it calling a full blown instance of Visual studio as a Script Editor Utility. This is typically the issue when SSDT installs are not done as a "NEW" or full install. It will attempt to utilize a version of Visual studio installed and its takes much longer to load.

Comment: Its using full blown visual studio 2015, i have installed VS complete from new and then installed the SSDT.

Comment: yes but in the SSDT installation did you install as a new instance or an existing instance of sql server. Clicking that there is an existing instance of sql service during the install will not hook the VS shell properly and you will be loading far more components in the script editor call then necessary.

Comment: You are correct i had sql 2012 developer edition already installed, when i installed the ssdt for visual studio 2015 i didn't add a new instance. Are you aware of a way to resolve this, apart from uninstall all and start over?? thanks again for the help, appreciate it.

Comment: you should be able to run the installer again and it should not effect any files that already exist. I would take a backup of your dev files just to be safe. Select that its a new install even though its not. This should install a vs shell of 2013 if I am not mistaken. This shell is a light weight version of Visual Studio that is really only good for editing scripts. this should shorten the load time for you as it will not have to load up the baggage that Visual Studio normally comes with. This will also ensure that you ssms sdk's are hooked as well.

Comment: I just tried what you suggest and reinstalled as new instance. However, it still opens the script in a new Visual Studio window. Has there been a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean up your temp folder, could help if you use it for temp files in your etl

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp

One more thing - did you get an new antivirus lately or changed policies ? Once I had this problem and Sophos really killed any performance of my visual studio. We set it to reads only and performance went up.