# SSIS Script Component takes long time to Open on Edit | VS 2017

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017, script-component

When I edit a script component on SSIS, it takes upwards of 30 seconds for a new instance of visual studio to open so I can edit it.

This makes debugging and making small changes very time consuming. I will be using SSIS packages a lot going forward, and I was looking for a way to speed up this process. 
The closest solution to my problem was found here:

[ssis vsta script component slow to open on edit VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879141/ssis-vsta-script-component-slow-to-open-on-edit-vs2015)

But this didn't seem to resolve my issue after reinstalling SSIS as a new instance.
Has there been a fix for this in VS 2017?

Comment: Welcome to joys of SSIS

Comment: Try using safe mode, use `devenv.exe /safemode` command

Comment: is there a disadvantage to using this?

Comment: It might be worth reviewing what services you are running on your local workstation/laptop. If this is a recent performance degradation, have you added anything new?

Comment: The only extensions I currently have is the Business Intelligence and GitHub

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this?